# rails call back update database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, callback

I have a Task Order that has_many Invoices. Task Order has an attribute called "invoicedAmount". Invoice has an attribute called "amount". I am trying to make a callback where whenever I add or delete an invoice, the "invoicedAmount" field updates accordingly. Right now I am able to make it calculate on the fly, but now I want to save it to the database. Here is my Invoice model:

```
class Invoice < ActiveRecord::Base

belongs_to :task_order
validates_presence_of :task_order_id


after_save :update_task_order_invoiced_amount, notice: ':)!'
after_destroy :update_task_order_invoiced_amount

def update_task_order_invoiced_amount

  @task_orders = TaskOrder.all
  @invoices = Invoice.all
  @task_orders.each do |task_order|
    task_order.invoicedAmount = task_order.invoices.sum(:amount)
  end

end

end
```

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably don't want to recalculate all `TaskOrder` records, but only changed one. So your `update_task_order_invoiced_amount` should look something like this:

```
def update_task_order_invoiced_amount
  task_order.invoicedAmount = task_order.invoices.sum(:amount)
  task_order.save
end
```

Comment: thanks @edariedl - I tried that but it still isnt working (i checked by doing a query console)...

Comment: First of all, you should probably use name `invoiced_amount` (conventions), but do you have `invoicedAmount` column in database? What was return from console? It worked for me in a console.

Comment: yes I have invoicedAmount.. I'll change it later to adhere to conventions. The return from console was 'nil'. My console command was 'TaskOrder.first.invoicedAmount' - I specifically added invoices to the first task order.

Comment: What it returns when you try to run `TaskOrder.first.invoices.sum(:amount)`?

Comment: It returns a big decimal value @edariedl

Comment: Can you add code of your `TaskOrder` model? This looks like it cannot save `task_order`, so you can try to use line `task_order.save(validate: false)` instead of `task_order.save`.

Comment: it is still 'nil' when I typed in  'TaskOrder.first.invoicedAmount'

Comment: Ok, one more idea try to change it to `task_order.save!` (exclamation mark at the end). But code of `TaskOrder` would be really helpful.

Comment: It still doesnt work :/ Here is my TaskOrder model:

class TaskOrder < ActiveRecord::Base

 belongs_to :contract
 has_many :invoices, :dependent => :destroy
 validates_presence_of :id
 validates_uniqueness_of :id
 self.primary_key = :id

end

Comment: Try to add `raise task_order.invoices.sum(:amount).to_s` before `task_order.save`, it should raise exception and show some number in exception name, something like `RuntimeError: 2420.0`. If it doesn't show number, you have a problem, that callbacks are not executed.

Comment: actually, doing task_order.save! works; I forgot to uncomment my callback when I tried it earlier. thank you so much!!